# Fragment flashes when removing

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

if I remove a fragment after setting it's View to Visibility View.GONE/ View.INVISIBLE the removal of the fragment causes the View to flash again before removing. how can i avoid this

```
fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Afterwards:

```
ft.remove(fragment);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

I am not using hide because I do the Animation by myself and at onAnimationEnd I do commit the remove.

Then the View of the Fragment flashes and then is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with setting the height to 0 and INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE:

```
fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =  fragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.height = 0;
fragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```